# Sorting data in xsl fo for PDF output using XSLT V 1.0

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

This is a question that I realize has been asked a million different ways already with just as many different solutions, but try as I might, I just can't find a solution that will give me the desired effect I want. I am creating xsl fo templates to give to Apache FOP to render a PDF. The PDF I am rendering is fairly straight forward, it simply has a table with repeating rows in it, and I want to control the order that the rows render in based on sorting a child tag of the repeating node I selected based on it's integer value.

My XML looks like this...

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Stops>
     <Stop>
      <Sequence>1</Sequence>
       <Address>
       <Street>123 main st</Street>
       <City>Toronto</City>
       <Postal_Code>L1G4F4</Postal_Code>
      </Address>
     </Stop>
     <Stop>
      <Sequence>3</Sequence>
      <Address>
       <Street>1441 First st</Street>
       <City>Toronto</City>
       <Postal_Code>L1G4F4</Postal_Code>
      </Address>
     </Stop>
     <Stop>
      <Sequence>2</Sequence>
      <Address>
       <Street>467 Center st</Street>
       <City>Vancouver</City>
       <Postal_Code>L9V4A1</Postal_Code>
      </Address>
     </Stop>
    </Stops>
```

My xslfo code looks like...

```
<fo:table> 
 <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(50)" column-number="1"/>
 <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(50)" column-number="2"/>
 <fo:table-body>
  <xsl:call-template name="sort-stops"/>
  </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

With...

```
<xslt:template select="Stops" name="sort-stops">
 <xsl:sort slect="stop/sequence"/>
 <xsl:for-each select="stop">
  <fo:table-row>
   <fo:table-cell>
    <fo:block>
     <xsl:value-of select="sequence"/>
    </fo:block>
   </fo:table-cell>
  </fo:table-row>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xslt:template>
```

There is obviously something wrong with my approach to this, but I have no idea where to go from here anymore. If I stick in simple code to insert a block in my sort-stops template definition, that will show up, but it really seems like the problem is in how I access the child nodes of my stop element. Can anyone please give me some direction as to how I can have the table rows sort the stops based on the sequence tag and genreate repeating rows in this order?

Comment: The `xsl:sort` element must be a child of either `xsl:apply-templates` or `xsl:for-each`.

Comment: Sorry, I realized I forgot to type the select statement for the template, does the select statement allow you to reference child elements as you would inside a for-each statement?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "select statement"; `select` is an **attribute** of several xsl elements. If you're asking if `xsl:sort` can be a child of `xsl:template`, the answer is no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't post your required output, but I am guessing you want to do something like this:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:table> 
        <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(50)" column-number="1"/>
        <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(50)" column-number="2"/>
        <fo:table-body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Stops/Stop">
                <xsl:sort select="Sequence" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Stop">
    <fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="Sequence"/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which given your example input will produce:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:table xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(50)" column-number="1"/>
   <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(50)" column-number="2"/>
   <fo:table-body>
      <fo:table-row>
         <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block>1</fo:block>
         </fo:table-cell>
      </fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-row>
         <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block>2</fo:block>
         </fo:table-cell>
      </fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-row>
         <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block>3</fo:block>
         </fo:table-cell>
      </fo:table-row>
   </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

Note that XML is case-sensitive; `select="sequence"` does **not** select `<Sequence>`.

Comment: Note: If this is a part of a larger solution, then you should test count(Stops/Stop) is greater than "0" before rendering the table. i.e. xsl:if test="count(Stops/Stop) > 0". Otherwise you would end up with an empty table-body which not a legal XSL FO construct.

Comment: Thank you, this solution works perfectly, I really appreciate the detail and clarity of your answer.

Comment: @jaks Possibly, but not for this.